# How to get 2 ArrayList in different class?

Tags: java, arrays, list, oop, collections

I have two class `Student` and `Worker`.
In that I define two `ArrayList` and have a getter for each class.

`Worker` Class:

```
private List<Worker> WorkerList = new ArrayList<Worker>();

public List<Worker> getWorkerList() {
    return WorkerList;
}

public Worker(String first, String last, float WeekSalary,
        float WorkingHours) {
    super(first, last);
    this.setWeekSalary(WeekSalary);
    this.setWorkingHoursPerDay(WorkingHours);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

`Student` Class:

```
private List<Student> StudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

public Student(String first, String last, int gradeValue) {
    super(first, last);
    this.setGrade(gradeValue);
}

public List<Student> getStudentList() {
    return StudentList;
}
```

The problem here is how can I get these two `ArrayList` from another class? For example a `MergeClass`?

Comment: What does "I defined an ArrayList" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MergeClass<T>
{
    private List<T> a;
    private List<T> b;
    public MergeClass(List<T> a, List<T> b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void merge()
    {
       //
    }
}
```

From what I understand is that what you need. Hope that it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the getter methods in `MergeClass`. You can have something like:

```
Worker w = new Worker();
Student s = new Student();
List<Worker> workerList = w.getWorkerList();
List<Student> studList = s.getStudentList();
```